# Building a new module that loads articles not adding slashes in front of images

Tags: articles, ajax, images

i am currently building a new module that loads joomla articles via ajax. During the final tests I noticed that image links are (relative links) not handled correctly. If an image is added to an article, it will be saved without leading slash. Apparently Joomla adjusts this itself and adds a slash when the article is loaded normally. But not via my Ajax Call:

Stored in the database: `....<img src="images/some-image.jpg">....`

Displayed in the browser: `....<img src="/images/some-image.jpg">....`

If loaded by my module: `....<img src="images/some-image.jpg">...`

This of course leads to the problem that images are not displayed.
What do I have to refer to so that Joomla! helps me to correct the paths?

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by `System - SEF` plugin. It will not work with page content added using JavaScript. You'll have to handle this in your code.